# How do I use ScaLapack/PBLAS for Matrix-Vector Multiplication?

Tags: lapack, blas

After going to all possible "Introductions" to ScaLapack, I still can't understand how to carry out a simple `PDGEMV` operation using it.

Here is what I must do :

I have to generate a matrix using

```
do i=1,n
  x(i) = i*i*1.0D+00
  do j=1,n
    A(i,j) = (i+j)*j*1.00D+00
  end do
end do
```

and then simply multiply `Matrix A by Vector x (b=Ax)`.

For Lapack, I simply use 
`CALL DGEMV('N',n,n,1.0D+00,a,n,x,1,0.0D+00,b,1)`

How do I achieve this in PBLAS? I have run the sample (`example1.f` from the website) program and it works.

What is partitioning of the matrix? How do I do it?

Everyone (in tutorials) seem to be concentrating on `DGESV` while I want `DGEMV/DGEMM` i.e. `BLAS`

Comment: Google is your friend. Look at http://scv.bu.edu/~kadin/PACS/HTML/blas21.html (somewhere at the middle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data distribution scalapack requires is a [block-cyclic](http://netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node75.html) [distribution](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/factor/node3.html).   (A little interactive calculator is [here](http://acts.nersc.gov/scalapack/hands-on/datadist.html)).   Once you get the hang of that, Scalapack is pretty straightforward.

For a given blocksize (which is a free parameter) and decomposition of the processors into a grid (eg, 4 processors -> 2 rows, 2 columns of processors) you can go from the local indices of your chunk of the matrix to the global indices of the matrix using l2g or g2l from [this NERSC example](http://www.nersc.gov/users/software/programming-libraries/math-libraries/libsci/libsci-example/); that's a pretty straightforward way to get started.   Row or column vectors are treated as nx1 or 1xn matrices.

Below is an example of multiplying the diagonal matrix A (1,2,3...) by a unit vector X and getting the results into Y; the only real trick here is that not all processors have a chunk of the X or Y vectors.

```
program gemv1
      use mpi
      implicit none

      integer :: n, nb    ! problem size and block size
      integer :: myArows, myAcols   ! size of local subset of global matrix
      integer :: myXrows, myXcols   ! size of local subset of global vector
      integer :: i,j, myi, myj
      real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: myA,myX,myY
      integer :: ierr

      integer, external :: numroc   ! blacs routine
      integer :: me, procs, icontxt, prow, pcol, myrow, mycol  ! blacs data
      integer :: info    ! scalapack return value
      integer, dimension(9)   :: ides_a, ides_x, ides_y ! matrix descriptors
      integer, dimension(2) :: dims
      real :: error, globerror

! Initialize blacs processor grid

      call blacs_pinfo   (me,procs)

! create as square as possible a grid of processors

      dims = 0
      call MPI_Dims_create(procs, 2, dims, ierr)
      prow = dims(1)
      pcol = dims(2)

! create the BLACS context

      call blacs_get     (0, 0, icontxt)
      call blacs_gridinit(icontxt, 'R', prow, pcol)
      call blacs_gridinfo(icontxt, prow, pcol, myrow, mycol)

! Construct local arrays
! Global structure:  matrix A of n rows and n columns

      n = int(25000.*sqrt(dble(procs)))

! blocksize - a free parameter.

      nb = 100

! how big is "my" chunk of matrix A?

      myArows = numroc(n, nb, myrow, 0, prow)
      myAcols = numroc(n, nb, mycol, 0, pcol)

! how big is "my" chunk of vector x?

      myXrows = numroc(n, nb, myrow, 0, prow)
      myXcols = 1

! Initialize local arrays    

      allocate(myA(myArows,myAcols)) 
      allocate(myX(myXrows,myXcols)) 
      allocate(myY(myXrows,myXcols)) 

      myA = 0.
      do myj=1,myAcols
          ! get global index from local index
          call l2g(myj,mycol,n,pcol,nb,j)
          do myi=1,myArows
              ! get global index from local index
              call l2g(myi,myrow,n,prow,nb,i)
              if (i == j) myA(myi,myj) = i
          enddo
      enddo

      myX = 0.
      call l2g(1,mycol,n,pcol,nb,j)
      if (j == 1) then
          do myi=1,myXrows
              call l2g(myi,myrow,n,prow,nb,i)
              myX(myi,1) = 1.
          enddo
      endif

      myY = 0.

! Prepare array descriptors for ScaLAPACK 

      call descinit( ides_a, n, n, nb, nb, 0, 0, icontxt, myArows, info )
      call descinit( ides_x, n, 1, nb, nb, 0, 0, icontxt, myXrows, info )
      call descinit( ides_y, n, 1, nb, nb, 0, 0, icontxt, myXrows, info )

! Call ScaLAPACK library routine

      call psgemv('N',n,n,1.,mya,1,1,ides_a,myx,1,1,ides_x,1,0.,myy,1,1,ides_y,1)
      if (me == 0) then
        if (info /= 0) then
             print *, 'Error -- info = ', info
        endif
      endif

! Deallocate the local arrays

      deallocate(myA, myX)

! Print results - Y should be 1,2,3...

      error = 0.
      call l2g(1,mycol,n,pcol,nb,j)
      if (j == 1) then
          do myi=1,myXrows
              call l2g(myi,myrow,n,prow,nb,i)
              error = error + (myY(myi,1)-1.*i)**2.
          enddo
      endif

      call MPI_Reduce(error, globerror, 1, MPI_REAL, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

      if (me == 0) then
        print *,'Y l2 error = ', sqrt(globerror/n)
      endif

      deallocate(myY)

! End blacs for processors that are used

      call blacs_gridexit(icontxt)
      call blacs_exit(0)

contains

! convert global index to local index in block-cyclic distribution

   subroutine g2l(i,n,np,nb,p,il)

   implicit none
   integer, intent(in) :: i    ! global array index, input
   integer, intent(in) :: n    ! global array dimension, input
   integer, intent(in) :: np   ! processor array dimension, input
   integer, intent(in) :: nb   ! block size, input
   integer, intent(out):: p    ! processor array index, output
   integer, intent(out):: il   ! local array index, output
   integer :: im1   

   im1 = i-1
   p   = mod((im1/nb),np)
   il  = (im1/(np*nb))*nb + mod(im1,nb) + 1

   return
   end subroutine g2l

! convert local index to global index in block-cyclic distribution

   subroutine l2g(il,p,n,np,nb,i)

   implicit none
   integer :: il   ! local array index, input
   integer :: p    ! processor array index, input
   integer :: n    ! global array dimension, input
   integer :: np   ! processor array dimension, input
   integer :: nb   ! block size, input
   integer :: i    ! global array index, output
   integer :: ilm1   

   ilm1 = il-1
   i    = (((ilm1/nb) * np) + p)*nb + mod(ilm1,nb) + 1

   return
   end subroutine l2g

end program gemv1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the pblas GEMV.

http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/pblas_qref.html#PvGEMV

Comment: I know I have to use that. My question is **how**? What is a submatrix, how do I generate it?